# Laravel 5 database setup

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I have installed laravel 5 on my mac using composer.

I am struggling with database configuration.
after i remove the ENV() in database.php setting, to without ENV(), it works.

The access is denied error is solved, however, why i cannot open localhost/phpmyadmin?

I read the few source about locating the .env file, however seems like i cannot locate it.
How do i properly setup database and how do i open localhost/phpmyadmin as now it says that access denied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using homestead? Or did you install Laravel directly on your system?

Comment: localhost/phpmyadmin is not related to your laravel. It's related to your local server. Which web server package you're using ?

Comment: I see..
After some time and refreshing, i can access to it now.
@SumonMahmud

Comment: I am not using homestead , i am using only composer @AshMenhennett

Comment: Laravel doesn't ship with a **.env** file out of the box. Instead of removing ENV() you should be able to rename **.env.example** to **.env** and setting up your Database credentials in there.